# Using Java to create a PayPal invoice

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Most of the GitHub example repositories/code examples that I have tried to find on this topic have been incomplete/outdated or have no documentation which leaves me no room to explore or expand.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is:

- Given the customer PayPal email (the person to send an invoice to)
- Given the amount specified

How can I successfully create an invoice from my own PayPal account using Java and send it over to the requested user/email? I have tried many of the examples found [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/sample/InvoiceSample.java), [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/), [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call) and [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/tree/master/rest-api-sample) however all of these websites/tools, as I mentioned are incomplete and do not offer any insight on how to properly send an invoice.

A detailed walkthrough or explanation on how to properly do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are asking for quite some stuff. Could you precise what exactly is unclear to you or missing? The question is kinda lacking some focus on a specific single problem, instead of the broad topic of PayPal invoices.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the PayPal-Java-SDK for anything (neither Invoices, nor anything else). It is deprecated.

The current version of PayPal Invoicing [is documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/regional/th/invoicing/basic-integration/) There is no SDK for it. Use direct HTTPS API calls (first obtaining an access_token using your client_id and secret)

If it is useful to you, you can use some of the Java code in the [Checkout-Java-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK) as a starting point (not its samples, the actual SDK's code)

For instance, the access token request code https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK/blob/develop/checkout-sdk/src/main/java/com/paypal/core/request/AccessTokenRequest.java

Comment: I'm really unsure as to how to get started with the invoice documentation, and how to send it out.

Comment: Start by getting a REST API access token, then use it for the API calls to create and send an invoice